# Capturing an image of one View Controller from another Class

Tags: ios, uigraphicscontext

I have one `MainViewController`, on top of that I am adding a `UIView` `iSnap` which is another Class.

Now I want to capture a part of `MainViewController` view in class `iSnap`.
Is it possible ?

I know how to capture the image from current View Controller's View, but here I want to capture view portion of `MainViewController` in `iSnap` class.

**This code I am using for capturing the image, which resides in iSnap Class.**

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(grabRect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
} else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(grabRect.size);
}
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -grabRect.origin.x, -grabRect.origin.y);
[self.layer renderInContext:ctx];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer:

```
 UIView *parentView = self.superview; //MainViewController is the superview of iSnap

if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(grabRect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
} else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(grabRect.size);
}
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -grabRect.origin.x, -grabRect.origin.y);
[parentView.layer renderInContext:ctx];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```